# I have to build an api that can save the data each time when it is updated and also to show the previous one in nodejs

Tags: node.js, nodes

how to build this type of api that can store the data previous data and current data.
this is current data

```
{
"email" : "iqbal.kashif60@gmail.com",
"username": "kashif786",
"phone": "8864005925"
}
after the update 
{
"email": "iqbal.kashif60@gmail.com",
"username": "kashif786",
"phone": "8864005926",
}
```

now history of data is

```
{
"email": "iqbal.kashif60@gmail.com",
"username": "kashif786",
"phone": "8864005926"
change: {
"phone": "8864005925",
"current_change": "8864005926"
}
}
```

so after each entity change it will show whole history who have change and which data changes if someone help me that will great .

Comment: Are you using a database or just saving in files ?

Comment: no i am using mongoose

Comment: i don't have any idea how to build this type of api if u give any reference link that will be great to me ..

Comment: ok so you are using mongodb you can use two collection for for actual records other for history

Comment: use expressjs with mongodb and mongoose as typorm watch this vedio https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fgTGADljAeg&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified

Comment: i have to build an api that can save updated data with previous data and current data please share me any reference document or github docs

Comment: this video only share how to build rest api

Comment: how many fields can be changed?

Comment: What else you want entire program ?

Comment: it depend on update api i have to take a record of previous data and updated data who is updating